# How to filter cities based on province selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm developing a web app feature where the City dropdown values should filter based on the selected Province. Currently, when you select either the Province or the City dropdown, it doesn't filter at all.

Here's what I've tried so far but it doesn't work:

**Header component (attempted filtering logic lives here):**

```
export const Header = ({ data, isLoading, error }: HeaderProps) => {
  ...

  // Bring in global state
  const {
    provinceDropdownFilter,
    cityDropdownFilter,
  } = useFilterStore();

  const filteredData = data.map((group) => group.equipments).flat();
  
  ...

  const handleDropdownFilterProvince = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    useFilterStore.setState({ provinceDropdownFilter: e.target.value });

    // Filter the data based on the selected province
    const filteredCitiesSet = new Set<string>(
      filteredData
        .filter((item) => item.state === e.target.value)
        .map((item) => item.city)
    );

    const filteredCities = Array.from(filteredCitiesSet);

    useFilterStore.setState({ filteredCities: filteredCities });
    console.log("handle province dropdown cities", filteredCities);
  };

  const handleDropdownFilterCity = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    useFilterStore.setState({ cityDropdownFilter: e.target.value });
  };

  ...

  return (
    <>
      ...
          <Dropdown
            data={data}
            value={manufacturerDropdownFilter}
            onChange={handleDropdownFilterManufacturer}
            filterType="manufacturer"
          />
          <Dropdown
            data={data}
            value={provinceDropdownFilter}
            onChange={handleDropdownFilterProvince}
            filterType="state"
          />
          <Dropdown
            data={data}
            value={cityDropdownFilter}
            onChange={handleDropdownFilterCity}
            filterType="city"
          />
     ...
    </>
  );
};
```

**Dropdown component:**

```
export const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps> = ({
  data,
  onChange,
  value,
  filterType,
}) => {
  ...

  const filteredData = data.map((group) => group.equipments).flat();

  // Filter the data based on the filterType
  const filteredOptions = filteredData.filter((i) => {
    if (filterType === "manufacturer") {
      return i.manufacturer;
    }
    if (filterType === "state") {
      return i.state;
    }
    if (filterType === "city") {
      return i.city;
    }

    return false;
  });

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        aria-label="Select"
        placeholder={getCustomPlaceholder(filterType) as string}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleFilters}
      >
        {Array.from(uniqueValues)
          .sort()
          .map((value) => (
            <option key={value} value={value}>
              {value}
            </option>
          ))}
      </Select>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Zustand Store:**

```
const useFilterStore = create<FilterState>(
  zukeeper((set: any) => ({
    ...
    provinceDropdownFilter: "",
    cityDropdownFilter: "",
    filteredCities: [],
    ...
    setProvinceDropdownFilter: (value: string) =>
      set({ provinceDropdownFilter: value }),
    setCityDropdownFilter: (value: string) =>
      set({ cityDropdownFilter: value }),
    setFilteredCitiesFilter: (value: string[]) =>
      set({ filteredCities: value }),
    ...
  }))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1:**

```js
useFilterStore.setState({ provinceDropdownFilter: e.target.value });

// Filter the data based on the selected province
const filteredCities = filteredData
  .filter((item) => item.state === e.target.value)
  .map((item) => item.city);

// Set the filtered city dropdown options
useFilterStore.setState({ cityDropdownFilter: filteredCities });
```

The `cityDropdownFilter` expects a string value like `provinceDropdownFilter`, but you are passing `filteredCities` which is an array of strings.

---

**Issue 2:**

```js
<Dropdown
  data={data}
  value={provinceDropdownFilter}
  onChange={handleDropdownFilterProvince}
  filterType="state"
/>

<Dropdown
  data={data}
  value={cityDropdownFilter}
  onChange={handleDropdownFilterCity}
  filterType="city"
/>
```

You are passing the full `data` as props on both province and city dropdowns, so it will always show you the unfiltered data. For city dropdown, you may want to filter the full data by province and pass an array of objects that match the province value (not just the array of city values like `filteredCities`

---

**Possible Approach:**

So, you may have to rewrite the logic something like below,

```js
export const Header = ({ data, isLoading, error }: HeaderProps) => {
  // Bring in global state
  const { provinceDropdownFilter, cityDropdownFilter } = useFilterStore();

  const filteredData = data.map((group) => group.equipments).flat();

  const [cityDropdown, setCityDropdown] = useState([]);

  const handleDropdownFilterProvince = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    useFilterStore.setState({ provinceDropdownFilter: e.target.value });

    // Filter the data based on the selected province
    const filteredCities = filteredData.filter(
      (item) => item.state === e.target.value
    );
    setCityDropdown(filteredCities);
  };

  const handleDropdownFilterCity = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    useFilterStore.setState({ cityDropdownFilter: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown
        data={data}
        value={provinceDropdownFilter}
        onChange={handleDropdownFilterProvince}
        filterType="state"
      />
      <Dropdown
        data={cityDropdown}
        value={cityDropdownFilter}
        onChange={handleDropdownFilterCity}
        filterType="city"
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks James! I added your adjustments. When selecting a Province from the Province dropdown, there's an error thrown: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'city')`, and it points to the `return i.city;` line of code in my Dropdown component. It seems that it can't find the `city` from the API. 

Looks like the `filteredData` in the dropdown component isn't mapping any data, according to my console.logs.

Comment: ohkk.. now i see, you are passing raw `data` object for province dropdown.. but for city, we are processing it on several places, (1) Header component | `const filteredData = data.map((group) => group.equipments).flat();` (2) handleDropdownFilterProvince | `const filteredCities`
---
So the type of raw `data` and the processed `filteredCities` is different..

Comment: That's correct. So basically in the Dropdown component, the full `data` as a prop is being sent down into it. I've updated my code, and the `console.log("handle province dropdown cities", filteredCities);` spits out exactly what I need, but now I need to figure out how to get all of those filtered cities to show up inside of the City dropdown. Any idea? I figured I may have to edit this part from the dropdown: `{Array.from(uniqueValues)
          .sort()
          .map((value) => (
            <option key={value} value={value}>
              {value}
            </option>
          ))}`

Comment: A simpler fix would be to try removing `const filteredData = data.map((group) => group.equipments).flat();` from `Dropdown` component and pass the `filteredData` from `Header` component as value to the province and manufacturer `Dropdown` components' `data` props. For city dropdowns you may pass `filteredCities` to `data` props.